# Next-SEO, how do I get parentOrganization into the localBusiness schema?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

I have this schema currently, but moving it over to a new site with next-seo, but next-seo is very strict in some ways and I cannot add a "custom attribute"... it strips it. So, how do I get the "parentOrganization" (as you see below to work within the LocalBusiness schema? I do not want to add a seperate "Organization" Schema as the search engine could get confused as to which one it should look at.

OLD SCHEMA THAT I WANT TO PUT INTO MY NEW SITE WITH NEXT-SEO

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some description",
  "openingHours": "24 hours",
  "currenciesAccepted": "USD",
  "paymentAccepted": "Credit Card",
  "image": "some logo",
  "telephone": "some phone",
  "openingHoursSpecification":[{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    "opens": "00:00",
    "closes": "23:59"
  }],
  "parentOrganization": { // <--------- ADD THIS
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "org name",
    "award": "A+ Rating from the Better Business Bureau",
    "logo": "org logo",
    "url": "org url",
    "member": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Better Business Bureau"
    }
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.8",
    "reviewCount": "515"
  },
  "address": "some address",
  "priceRange": "$99"
}
```

Comment: That's not supported by `next-seo`. Either create a PR to enable support for it, or do not use `next-seo` for `LocalBusiness` schema.

Comment: blaaarg. seems a common use case. If not for nothing, they should allow for custom insertions.....